# Google Analytics ecommerce How to add product costs

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is it possible to add the product costs (buying price) to the javascript google analytics ecommerce plugin? I could not find something similar on the developers page. This would be interesting for me to get information about the profit we make besides the turn over etc.

Comment: Are you referring to standard ecommerce or enhanced? Can you elaborate on what it is exactly you want? Purchase price info can be added to your product transactions. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: I am referring to both API's. The purchase price is the "customer purchase" price --> my selling price. I need to add my product costs. In ex. I buy the product for 80$ (product costs / my purchase price) and sell it to the customer for 100$ --> Difference: 20$. This difference I want to see within google analytics to directly see my winnings and not only my revenue / turn over. Is that possible?

Comment: sorry, maybe I missunderstood the meaning, because my native language is german. I think revenue is that what I am looking for.

Comment: OK, I think you are looking for the profit margin (profit margin = revenue - cost of goods sold). To do this, you would need to create custom dimensions to include those data points in your ecommerce transaction. Here's an article that talks more about that: http://www.analytics-ninja.com/blog/2013/08/measuring-profit-using-googles-universal-analytics.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Since it's business specific, Google won't have any documentation about adding the cost of each product sold on the site to Google Analytics.

That said, Google does talk at great length about how to include custom data into Google Analytics. You'll want to create a custom metric (i.e., Cost of Goods Sold) that will represent the cost of a product and use the Data Import feature to upload those costs per product SKU.

Once the data is available in GA, you can start reporting on the COGS and in addition report on Gross Profit. To report on Gross Profit, create a calculated metric that subtracts the custom metric COGS from the standard metric Product Revenue.

For a more detailed explanation, check out http://online-metrics.com/gross-profit/, https://www.lynda.com/Google-Analytics-tutorials/Import-cost-goods-COGS-data/521154/564235-4.html, and http://www.practicalecommerce.com/Using-Google-Analytics-to-Track-Profitability-by-Product.